# "Runtime error 13 - Type mismatch" when parsing date from a text cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm importing a .csv file from another program into Excel. The date format is text, formatted as follows : 
mm/dd/yy or
07/03/17
The imported file is very unstructured, with more than just dates in the first field.

I want to write 2017-07-03 into the cell (2,13)

Here is the code I'm using

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-12]))=8, _  'How I identify date 
20&MID((RC[-12]),7,2)&" - "&                      'To get 2017 4 digit Year
MID((RC[-12]),1,2)&" - "&                         'To extract 2 digit month
MID((RC[-12]),4,2)),"""")"                        'To extract 2 digit day
```

This gives me Runtime error 13 - Type mismatch.
I think that my code is causing the error by mixing values and text, but I cannot see where.

Comment: I think you have an extra close parenthesis. Try `=IF(LEN(RC[-12])=8...`

Comment: on what line do you get your error?

Comment: I removed the parenthesis.  Same error

Comment: Actually ALL the above is in one line in my code and that line produces the error.

Comment: I broke it down just to make it more readable on this site.

Comment: What, exactly, is the content of `A2`?  I suspect there are easier ways to do what you want.

Comment: Partial contents of Col A

Comment: 11/28/16
120
305
310
300
Sales Tax Payable
Secondary Tax

Comment: That should have been Cell(1,1) 11/28/16   Cell(2,1) 120  Cell(3,1) 305, etc.  Didn't know how to format them on this site because Enter does not give m a new line to type.  Enter=Submit on this site.

Comment: OK, now I understand.

Comment: Give this a try: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-12])=8,20&MID(RC[-12],7,2)&"" - ""&MID(RC[-12],1,2)&"" - ""&MID(RC[-12],4,2),"""")"`

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for your error message is due to the formula not being properly created.

It should look like:

```
Cells(2, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-12])=8, 20 & MID(RC[-12],7,2) & ""-"" & MID(RC[-12],1,2) & ""-"" & MID(RC[-12],4,2),"""")"
```

Instead of writing formulas to the worksheet, I suggest doing the conversion within VBA and then writing the results to the worksheet.  This can make your code easier to understand, debug, and maintain in the future.

The code below could be shortened, but purposely is not so as to provide more clarity.  It is written as a macro that will process everything in column A, and write the dates to column M, in the format you specify.

I note that in your question, you specify a format of `2017-07-03`, but in your code, you generate a format of `2017 - 07 - 03`.  I generated the former in the code, but it should be obvious how to change to the latter if that is what you really want.

Also note that in the code I used the default conversion for Excel for 2-digit years, where two digit years are assumed to be in the range `1930 - 2029`.  That can be changed if necessary.

The code uses a more involved method of assuring the value being converted is truly a date.  But it does not check for "illegal" dates and will convert, for example `2/31/17`  to `2017-03-03`.  Your formula method would return the string `2017-02-31`  It would be trivial, in the VBA macro, to add code to flag this kind of problem, if it might be an issue.

There are other ways to check for valid dates, including seeing if `CDate` or VBA's `DateValue` functions return a date or an error.  But these may not work properly across workbooks in different locale's, with different default short date formats in the windows Regional Settings.

Instead of writing the results as text, the results could be written as a real date formatted as you wish with the `.numberformat` property of the cell (which could be used in future calculations), and that option is in the comments in the macro.

If you require that the result be dynamic, with a formula, the macro could be easily converted into a User Defined Function, but you would have to assure that the cell format is "text" else Excel will try to convert the resultant date into a "real date" (depending on which of the two formats you really want).

Post back with any questions about the code.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertOnlyDates()
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim YR As Long, MN As Long, DY As Long
    Dim DT As Date

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, C As Range

'Define the range to check:  Columns A
'Always best to explicitly define worksheets and cells
'  and not rely on ActiveSheet, Activate, Select, etc
Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2")
With WS
    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each C In rSrc

    'check if a date
    V = Split(C.Text, "/")
        If UBound(V) = 2 Then
            If V(0) > 0 And V(0) <= 12 _
                And V(1) > 0 And V(1) <= 31 _
                And V(2) >= 0 And V(2) <= 99 Then

                    MN = V(0)
                    DY = V(1)

                    'note that this is Excel's default (at least for now)
                    YR = V(2) + IIf(V(2) < 30, 2000, 1900)

                    DT = DateSerial(YR, MN, DY)

                    'Can be written as text
                    '  or as a real date with proper formatting

                    '  REAL DATE
                    'With C.Offset(0, 12) 'write in column M
                    '    .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                    '    .Value = DT
                    'End With

                    With C.Offset(0, 12)
                        .NumberFormat = "@"
                        .Value = Format(DT, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                    End With
                End If
            End If
Next C

End Sub
```

---

Comment: You are truly amazing!  Such a clear and detailed response is greatly appreciated.  I will try your code in my program later today.

Comment: For future reference, I would like to know how to avoid a type mismatch error.  What I want is IF(LEN(A1)=8 then "123" else "456".  This generates a type mismatch error.  When I replace "123" and "456" with 123 and 456 there is no error.  How can I get the desired "123" and "456" without getting a type mismatch error?

Comment: @BPfromCanada You can avoid type mismatch errors by ensuring that the variables to which you are assigning values are of the same data type as the value being assigned.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't appropriately closed your strings with double quotes for each line. Using the continuation character `_` doesn't allow you to break a string in the middle. You can do this if you properly concatenate:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-12]))=8," & _       'How I identify date 
                         "20&MID((RC[-12]),7,2)&" - " & _ 'To get 2017 4 digit Year
                         "MID((RC[-12]),1,2)&" - " & _    'To extract 2 digit month
                         "MID((RC[-12]),4,2)),"""")"      'To extract 2 digit day
```

(Your code will be far more readable if you take the time to indent continued lines in the fashion shown above. You can more quickly and easily pick out the destination variable and the assignment if you follow this format.)

Comment: I re-typed the code snippet to try to make it more readable but, in doing so, I left out a few _'s.  Here is exactly the code, copied from my computer. ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-12])=8, 20&MID((RC[-12]),7,2)&" - "&MID((RC[-12]),1,2)&" - "&MID((RC[-12]),4,2)),"""")"